# Can Burp Suite uses SOCKS 4 upstream proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks, burp

I'm trying to use the Burp Suite Pro to scan a web application through a SOCKS 4 proxy (Cobalt Strike). But when I try, the proxy server resets the TCP connection.

So I fired wireshark to check what was happening between the two and I saw that the Burp Suite was using **SOCKS version 5** to connect to my **SOCKS version 4** proxy.

Is there a way to tell Burp Suite to use SOCKS 4 instead of 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off the "Do DNS lookups over SOCKS proxy" option, because SOCKS 4 doesn't support that? Therefore interaction between a SOCKS 5 client and a SOCKS 4 server should be just the same as a SOCKS 4 client and SOCKS 4 server since the web doesn't use UDP.

[See here for option descriptions](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/options_connections.html).

Alternatively, try [their official support site](https://support.portswigger.net/).